# Is there an operator for 'contained in set or subset or subset of subset' and so on?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I have a set, the elements of which may be sets, some of which may have sets as elements in turn, and so on. Is there an operator or a convenient way to express this relationship?

Comment: In most standard versions of set theory, the assumption is that *everything* is a set. Thus, what you describe would be just, well, a set.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear. The point is, $a \in \{b, c, \{d, a\}$ is false. Is there an operator instead of $\in$ I could use that would represent 'is in this set, or any subset thereof, or any subset of those, and so on'?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. It might be useful to write this as something like "$x\in \mathrm{tc}(X)$". Here $\mathrm{tc}(X)$ is the *transitive closure* of the set $X$, containing the elements of $X$, the elements of elements of $X$, the elements of elements of elements of $X$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you're looking for a "recursive membership" operator $\preceq$ which is defined by:

1. $x\in A$ implies that $x \preceq A$.
2. $x \preceq A$ and $A \preceq B$ implies that $x \preceq B$.

In other words, it is the transitive closure of the set membership relation.

I am not sure if a notation for this operator already exists, but this gives you a formal definition to invent it. You might use $\in^*$ for notation, by analogy with Kleene star notation.